# protobuf plugin to enhance generated java class

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I am looking for any example of using protobuf plugin architecture in practice.

Ultimately, I want to add custom annotations to generated java classes. But haven't gone far. I cannot quite understand how the insertion points https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#plugins work, and how can I tap into the generated files structure.

I am looking for any advise or example that can show me how can I do such a thing